# python selenium спуск внутрь по div

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

И так, есть drop down menu с числами (дата рождения), который генерируется через JS. Я отлаливаю весь HTML с числами:

данный div генерируется после клика по этому "drop down"

`days_drop_down = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath='//div[@data-test-id="select-menu-wrapper"]')`

Вот что внутри этого элемента:

Получил через `days_drop_down.get_attribute('innerHTML')`

```html
<div data-test-id="birth-date__day__menu" class="base-0-2-173 list-0-2-174" style="top: 41px;">
    <div class="base-0-2-179 dropdown-0-2-180">
        <div class="scrollViewport-0-2-178" style="max-height: 405px;">
            <div class="items-0-2-177">
                <div class="Select__option Select__option--is-focused css-0" id="react-select-2-option-0" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d0-0-2-190 focused-0-2-186" data-test-id="select-value:1" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">1</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-1" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d1-0-2-191" data-test-id="select-value:2" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">2</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-2" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d2-0-2-192" data-test-id="select-value:3" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">3</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-3" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d3-0-2-193" data-test-id="select-value:4" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">4</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-4" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d4-0-2-194" data-test-id="select-value:5" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">5</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-5" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d5-0-2-195" data-test-id="select-value:6" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">6</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-6" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d6-0-2-196" data-test-id="select-value:7" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">7</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-7" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d7-0-2-197" data-test-id="select-value:8" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">8</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-8" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d8-0-2-198" data-test-id="select-value:9" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">9</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-9" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d9-0-2-199" data-test-id="select-value:10" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">10</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-10" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d10-0-2-200" data-test-id="select-value:11" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">11</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-11" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d11-0-2-201" data-test-id="select-value:12" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">12</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-12" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d12-0-2-202" data-test-id="select-value:13" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">13</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-13" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d13-0-2-203" data-test-id="select-value:14" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">14</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-14" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d14-0-2-204" data-test-id="select-value:15" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">15</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-15" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d15-0-2-205" data-test-id="select-value:16" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">16</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-16" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d16-0-2-206" data-test-id="select-value:17" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">17</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-17" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d17-0-2-207" data-test-id="select-value:18" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">18</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-18" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d18-0-2-208" data-test-id="select-value:19" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">19</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-19" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d19-0-2-209" data-test-id="select-value:20" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">20</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-20" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d20-0-2-210" data-test-id="select-value:21" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">21</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-21" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d21-0-2-211" data-test-id="select-value:22" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">22</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-22" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d22-0-2-212" data-test-id="select-value:23" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">23</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-23" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d23-0-2-213" data-test-id="select-value:24" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">24</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-24" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d24-0-2-214" data-test-id="select-value:25" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">25</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-25" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d25-0-2-215" data-test-id="select-value:26" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">26</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-26" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d26-0-2-216" data-test-id="select-value:27" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">27</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-27" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d27-0-2-217" data-test-id="select-value:28" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">28</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-28" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d28-0-2-218" data-test-id="select-value:29" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">29</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-29" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d29-0-2-219" data-test-id="select-value:30" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">30</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__option css-0" id="react-select-2-option-30" tabindex="-1">
                    <div data-test-id="select-option-wrapper">
                        <div class="base-0-2-183 base-d30-0-2-220" data-test-id="select-value:31" data-test-disabled="false">
                            <div class="iconContainer-0-2-184"></div>
                            <div class="textContainer-0-2-185">
                                <span class="base-0-2-28 control-0-2-34 auto-0-2-50">31</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Собственно сам вопрос: как мне кликнуть например по числу 3? Я так понимаю, что мне нужно спуститься до `<div class="items-0-2-177">` и перебрать все `div`? Если да, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В своей задачи нашёл закономерность классов: `data-test-id="select-value:1"` соответствующий числу `1` и тд.

Т.е. Если я хочу кликнуть по элементу `3`:

`specific_day = days_drop_down.find_element_by_xpath(xpath='//div[@data-test-id="select-value:3"]')`

`specific_day.click()`

Но это решение сугубо в моей ситуации и я думаю есть более общее/правильное решение (на пример как я уже подумал, спуск до нужного `div` и дальше перебор с поиском нужного значения)